# JCosole can't connect to glassfish / change address of http listeners

Tags: glassfish, freebsd, jconsole

I run a FreeBSD 11.0 server at home, in my private network. I wanted to learn some Java EE, so I installed GlassFish 4.1 at the server. After creating a domain (domain1), I wanted to login in via JConsole. But I get this error message "Connection failed: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint". The ip of the server is 19.168.178.91, so I tried to connect to "192.168.178.91:8686" is that roight?

My other issue is, in the book, which I'm using, they install glassfish at the same machine, which is used use to programm, so they changed the address of the three http listeners, of the IIOP-listener and of the jmx-connector from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1. Should I change it to the ip of the server or just leave it like it is?

Thank you in advance